My variable is not interpolated in the body on emailext
This is a piece of my Jenkinsfile:
emailext([
        attachmentsPattern: '**/build/*.log',
        subject: 'Hello World',
        recipientProviders: [developers(), requestor()],
        to: '$DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS',
        body: '''
            <p>Test summary:</p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="${BUILD_URL}">Status: ${BUILD_STATUS}</a></li>
                <li><a href="${BUILD_URL}/flowGraphTable">Executed steps</a></li>
                <li><a href="${BUILD_URL}/parsed_console">Errors and warnings</a></li>
                <li>Test results:</li>
                ${testResults}
            </ul>
        ''',
        mimeType: 'text/html'
])

But unfortunately testResults variable doesn't get interpolated:

How can I fix?
Also, I have tried to replace ''' with """, like this:
emailext([
        attachmentsPattern: '**/build/*.log',
        subject: 'Hello World',
        recipientProviders: [developers(), requestor()],
        to: '$DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS',
        body: """
            <p>Test summary:</p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="${BUILD_URL}">Status: ${BUILD_STATUS}</a></li>
                <li><a href="${BUILD_URL}/flowGraphTable">Executed steps</a></li>
                <li><a href="${BUILD_URL}/parsed_console">Errors and warnings</a></li>
                <li>Test results:</li>
                ${testResults}
            </ul>
        """,
        mimeType: 'text/html'
])

But I got this error in my Jenkins console output:
Error when executing always post condition:
Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: 4fb4675f-4b24-4e5a-8344-835e9d514202
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: BUILD_STATUS for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Jenkins version is: 2.441

Your second attempt is the correct approached, it just looks like the parameter BUILD_STATUS is not defined in your pipeline and therefore the error. What version of Jenkins are you using? as BUILD_STATUS is only available since version 2.263.2, if you are using al older version try using currentBuild.currentResult.

@NoamHelmer Jenkins version is 2.441

Use """ not ''' if you want to do templating

@tim_yates Hello, I have already tried that as you can read in my post

These are two different errors.
The first one is caused by the difference between the single and the double quotes in Groovy, that are well described in String interpolation section of Jenkins documentation.
The second one obviously means that you don't have the BUILD_STATUS variable defined. It may depend on the type of the pipeline and Jenkins version, but here's a couple things I'd recommend to check:

AFAIR, Jenkins doesn't expose the build status as en environment variable like BUILD_URL, you have to use a Groovy variable currentBuild.result or something like that;
you might want to refer the environment variables as ${env.VARIABLE_NAME} because it will be a Groovy variable then - ${VARIABLE_NAME} might be not defined in this context simply because it's not a shell command. This works differently in usual pipelines and multibranch ones, so without more details it's impossible to suggest a precise solution.

Given that, I would try the following:
emailext([
        attachmentsPattern: '**/build/*.log',
        subject: 'Hello World',
        recipientProviders: [developers(), requestor()],
        to: $DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS,
        body: """
            <p>Test summary:</p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="${env.BUILD_URL}">Status: ${currentBuild.result}</a></li>
                <li><a href="${env.BUILD_URL}/flowGraphTable">Executed steps</a></li>
                <li><a href="${env.BUILD_URL}/parsed_console">Errors and warnings</a></li>
                <li>Test results:</li>
                ${testResults}
            </ul>
        """,
        mimeType: 'text/html'
])


@tail I've added a code snippet, maybe that helps.

This works. Just use ${currentBuild.currentResult} instead of ${currentBuild.result}

You are almost there with your triple-double-quote fix, you just need to pass the ${BUILD_STATUS} expression to the Token Macro plugin (emailext is using it to dynamically generate email subject and body) and prevent groovy from interpolating it too early. Try escaping the $ sign with \, like \${BUILD_STATUS}.

Hello, did you mean something like <li><a href="${BUILD_URL}">Status: \${BUILD_STATUS}</a></li>?

Exactly. You might need to do the same for BUILD_URL
